Unable to create domain for feature layer using ArcGIS Field Maps
I have a feature layer that I have exported from one of my Esri FieldMaps as a shapefile, and I am needing to create coded domains for some of the fields. However, the option to create or assign domains is not available in the Data Design menu.
Does this have anything to do with exporting the layers from ArcGIS Online?
I did not use the portal in ArcGIS Pro. I downloaded them directly from my ArcGIS Online account.

As commented by @Vince:

Shapefiles don't support coded domains. You need to use geodatabase.

Try exporting from ArcGIS Field Maps as a file geodatabase instead of as a shapefile because the latter does not support domains.
